# Hover effect only on parent div

Tags: javascript, css

I have a sidebar that expands on hover, right now im hiding the text with opacity and when i hover on the hidden spans it triggers the effect.

how can i solve this ? or maybe there is a better way to create this kind of effect that im looking for

Thanks in advance.

https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/2618/

```css
#sidebar {
  user-select: none;
  position: fixed;
  width: 55px;
  height: 100vh;
  background: #2c2c2c;
  transition: 0.5s;
}

#sidebar:hover {
  width: 250px;
}

#sidebar:hover .sidebar-item span {
  opacity: 1;
}

.sidebar-item {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  border-left: 5px solid transparent;
}

.sidebar-item span {
  opacity: 0;
  transition: 0.5s;
}
```

```html
<div id="sidebar">
  <div class="sidebar-wrapper">
    <div class="sidenav-menu d-flex flex-column flex-grow">
      <div class="sidebar-item">
        <a class="d-flex" href="/">
          <i class="fa fa-lg fa-home" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 20px"></i>
          <span>Home</span>
        </a>
      </div>
      <div class="sidebar-item">
        <a class="d-flex" href="/profile">
          <i class="fa fa-lg fa-user-o" style="margin-left: 1px; margin-right: 22px"></i>
          <span>Profile</span>
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: `how can i solve this ? ` Solve what? You didn't say what's wrong and what's the desired effect.

Comment: "when i hover on the hidden spans it triggers the effect" Roll over the "Home" or "Profile" label when the sidebar is hidden, it will trigger the effect

Comment: Why won't `overflow: hidden` on `#sidebar` work? I ran it in the fiddle and you get the desired effect...

Comment: @BrandonMowat Not sure, because it doesn't give the desired effect?

Comment: @Nope AFAIK it does. I compared both fiddles and it solves the issue where the spans triggered the effect.

Comment: @BrandonMowat Only asking because I see no behavior difference between OPs fiddle and the fiddle linked by the accepted answer :/

Comment: They both the same ... no ? lol

Comment: @AsafAviv Why would your fiddle be the same as the fiddle from the answer if yours suppose to have an issue which the answer suppose ot have fixed?

Comment: I thought we were talking about the accepted solution and BrandonMowats solution ...

Comment: @AsafAviv No, **OP** (Original Poster) refers to you and your question :) - I'm at a loss, or blind (prob blind) but the original fiddle, the fiddle post by the answer and the suggested overflow fix all result in the same behavior as your original fiddle and nothing changed. Not sure , as said, I'm prob blind :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You changed the opacity of your elements but they're still in the document and so they're triggering the effect.

By using `visibility: hidden / visible`, hovering the labels won't trigger the effect :

```
.sidebar-item span {
    opacity:0;
    transition: 0.5s;
    visibility : hidden
}       
#sidebar:hover .sidebar-item span{
    opacity:1;
    visibility : visible
}
```

[Your updated JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aq9Laaew/2704/)

Comment: This is one solution although, transitions with the `visibility` property can get a little weird. I would suggest `overflow: hidden` but for some reason that answer keeps getting downvoted..

Comment: @BrandonMowat Indeed, `overflow:hidden` works too. Don't know why it was downvoted.

Comment: Is there a way to reveal the span the same as the animation ? like they coming from outside together ?

Comment: @AsafAviv For that, I would apply a `transform: translateX(...)` on the span tags.

Answer (score 1):

I think you can fix your bug by setting `overflow: hidden` on `#sidebar`